# biblatex format bibliography list

Tags: biblatex

How to make the bibliography entries to be printed as a usual paragraph (with parindent without any other indentations) but with the index number without dot?

And also I need to make a skip between them.

Example:

```
    1  Autor A. A book in my bibliog-
raphy 1984

    2  Author2 A2. Another book name
in bibliography
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`biblatex` offers the command `\defbibenvironment` to customise the appearance of the bibliography.

```
\usepackage{calc}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{\printfield[labelnumberwidth]{labelnumber}}
    {\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
     \setlength{\labelsep}{1.5em}%
     \addtolength{\itemindent}{\labelsep+\labelnumberwidth}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

also we can redefine the formatting instruction in `labelnumberwidth`, namely:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\makebox[0pt][l]{#1}}
```

This puts the label number in a box with no width (so the `+\labelnumberwidth` above is redundant).

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine `DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{…}` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{testname.bib}
@article{jdoe,
    author={Doe, John Paul},
    journal={Journal},
    title={Title},
    year=2014,
    pages={111--222},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\hskip\parindent#1}
\addbibresource{testname.bib}

\begin{document}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text Citation: \cite{jdoe}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the proposed solution is not what the OP wanted. Successive lines in a bib entry are still indented as in a list environment.